Pytest doesn't found my settings directory
I tried to start pytest but the settings file cannot be found by pytest
I'm in virtualenv with Python 3.11.9 and pytest 8.3.2
ImportError: No module named 'drf.settings'
pytest-django could not find a Django project (no manage.py file could be found). You must explicitly add your Django project to the Python path to have it picked up.

here the structure of my project
├── README.md
├── drf
│   ├── drf
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── production_settings.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   └── tests
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   └── test_auth.cpython-311-pytest-8.3.2.pyc
│       ├── factory_boy
│       │   ├── __pycache__
│       │   │   └── factory_models.cpython-311.pyc
│       │   └── factory_models.py
│       └── test_auth.py
├── drf-uwsgi.ini
├── pytest.ini
├── requirements.in
├── requirements.txt

and here the content of pytest.ini
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = drf.settings
python_files = test_*.py
django_debug_mode = true
pythonpath = .venv/bin/python

What I have tried so far:

I tried to add init.py to tests directory (seems not be recommended and didn't worked)
deactivate and reactivate the virtualenv
change drf.settings.py for drf.drf.settings but nothing
run pytest as module with python -m pytest tests

edit:
at this moment I can run pytest with any problem, but I use a conftest for that and search a solution with pytest.ini
If you have any suggestions  ;)

This is related to your folder structure. pytest expects to be run from the same folder as your manage.py. You should consider to merge the top and the upper drf folder.

I tried your solution, I merged the upper to the top and add an init.py to the upper folder, I get a little different error this time:
ImportError: No module named 'drf.settings.py'; 'drf.settings' is not a package 

You need to add pythonpath within the pytest.ini as follows:
[pytest]
pythonpath = drf
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = drf.settings
python_files = test_*.py

Or you can change the layout of the tests and move the pytest.ini from the project's root to the tests folder like this SO post.

Note: use drf.settings instead of drf.settings.py

I try with the pythonpath but seems doesn't work, I have a virtualenv for my python so may it's the cause?

I try with a confetest.py with the content
`import os
import django
set up Django environment
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "drf.settings")
django.setup()`
that work but I read it's not recommended to use conftest

@jordan no, using virtualenv is not the case, it's normal to use. did you use DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = drf.settings within your pytest.ini properly without .py postfix?

yes, also, I updated the post with the actual pytest.ini

@jordan what is your command and the path for running the pytest?

I use pytest (python -m pytest work too) but I don't give any path

@jordan I mean the current path you are using the pytest command. anyway, the use case should be as follows: go to the project path, activate the venv source venv/bin/activate, install requirements as well as pytest, go to the drf/, enter pytest tests should work as long as the pythonpath = drf and DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = drf.settings within pytest.ini

@jordan you can also move the pytest.ini within the tests/ folder and change the pythonpath value to ../.

Oh sorry, I run from /Users/user/projects/account/django/drf
from drf I din't the conftest but I encoured another error, may it's another thing but Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, maybe it's better to open another post for that
